# Jquery changing image width via class

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to dynamically change the width of images via the value I get from a slider in Jquery

Firebug error

```
TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).css is not a function   
document.getElementsByClassName(".images").css("width", ui.value);
```

HTML

```
<div id="filmpkes">         
    <img class="images" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/A-Team-Logo.svg/600px-A-Team-Logo.svg.png" width="100px"/>            
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
$("#slider").slider(

    {   min:50,
        max:250,
        change:function(event,ui){
            alert(ui.value);
            document.getElementsByClassName(".images").css("width", ui.value);
        }           
    }               
);
});
```

EDIT :  Can't believe I mixed that up, thanks!

EDIT: 
Can't get the image to resize
http://jsfiddle.net/P5PLg/

Answer (score 1):

Check this code and replace with your js codes

```
$(function(){
$("#slider").slider(
    {   min:50,
        max:250,
        change:function(event,ui){
            alert(ui.value);
            $(".images").css("width", ui.value);
        }           
    }               
);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is there is not .css() method for vanilla JavaScript, if you know jQuery you can use:

`$(".images").css("width", ui.value);`

or in vanilla javascript:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("images");

images.forEach(function( image, index, images ) {

    image.style.width = ui.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing vanilla javascript with jQuery...
**And** if using plain vanilla JS you need to remove the `.` in `getElementsByClassName(".images")`

Try this:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("images");
$(images).css("width", ui.value);
```

Or (**even better**) with just jQuery it would look like:

```
$(".images").css("width", ui.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".images").css("width", ui.value);
```

Why not just use JQuery? The document does not have the CSS function.

```
$(".images").css("width", ui.value);
```